# Drawing streamlines of 2D water flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics

The $u$-component of a $2D$ water flow is given by $u=7x^2+2y^2$.

Is it possible to draw streamlines based on only this?

Comment: $7x^2+2y^2=c$ where $c$ is a constant represents an ellipse $E_c$... and all these ellipses are homothetical.

Comment: @JeanMarie Is there any way to find the $v$-component(if any)?

Comment: Yes, by using the Milne-Thomson method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milne-Thomson_method_for_finding_a_holomorphic_function)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks.